# Is there a way to retrieve multi-channel funnel data from google reporting v4 api?

Tags: google-analytics-api

Is there any multichannel funnel querying capabilities in reporting v4 API?

Any documentation I find is on obsolete "v3" Multi-channel API, and I wonder whether it makes sense using it, or there is some new alternative in v4 reporting API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The [MFC v3 api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/v3/) is far from obsolete or even deprecated. The [Analytics reporting API V4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/) only replaces the [Core Reporting API V3](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/). Other parts of the Analytics V3 API, such as the Management API, are still being actively maintained.